# inserting blob into sqlite from safari browser using html5

Tags: javascript, sqlite, pdf, safari, blob

I need to load/insert a pdf to a blob in my sqlite db, I'm using html5 and javascript.

I am using the sqlite db locally using html5 and safari browser, have a db going beautifully... just need to know how to insert a blob into the db from a pdf file on the same, obviously because it's local, box.

I imagine the sql would be something like insert into mytable columns (myblob) values ("/documents/myfile.pdf");

Any advice or direction is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to put this into a web sql database?  Wouldn't it make more sense to save the file using the filewriter api?    Do you need to support mobile browsers or something? http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Comment: @RyanLynch: Yeah, for mobile browsers too. And there will be no server only local filesystem.

Comment: Your use case is ambiguous.  I understand that you want to save/load a PDF... but why?  There may be an alternative strategy what will be better suited to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The SQL statement you've written will only insert the literal string "/documents/myfile.pdf" into the DB.  You're going to need some method to convert your PDF file to binary using JavaScript and then insert that binary code into your DB.  To retrieve from the DB, you'll need to convert the raw binary back to a PDF file.  Sounds like a real pain.  So, does the document really need to be PDF or can you settle for raw text of some sort... perhaps even HTML?

Answer (score 1):

To read the PDF from disk, you would use the `FileReader` interface of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/). See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ for a tutorial.

---

The [WebSQL API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) does not have data types for accessing blobs, so you have to convert the file contents to a textual INSERT command.

In SQLite, a [BLOB literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) is a string containing hexadecimal byte values, prefixed with an `x`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(myblob) VALUES(x'255044462d312e340d25e2e3cfd30d0a...');
```